# Powershell - How to add File Size to an existing Query

Tags: powershell

A user provided me with this query;

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter '*.*'  -recurse -File | 
Select-Object FullName, LastWriteTime |
Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending |
Export-Csv '!2023.01.24.AllFiles.csv' -NoTypeInformation -UseCulture
```

How can I add the file size to the last column?
I still need to sort by the LastWriteTime.

FYI: Powershell Noob here...

Looking around it seems that Length is my answer but I keep breaking the applet... :-/

Tried variations of this:

```
Select-Object -property Length

Select-Object Length
```

Originally I was hoping to add switches to this command

```
(gci -filter *.* -recurse).FullName > !!2023.01.24.AllFiles.txt
```

Comment: `Select-Object FullName, LastWriteTime` -> `Select-Object FullName, LastWriteTime, Length`

Comment: This is much easier for me to understand... Thank you.
Q: How can I round to 0 places and append " KB" at the end? That's <Space>KB

Comment: See [Paolo's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75233888/712649), change `{$_.length/1KB}` to `{"$($_.length/1KB) KB"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct that you can get the file size by pulling the length property; e.g.

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter '*.*'  -recurse -File | 
Select-Object FullName, LastWriteTime, Length |
Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending |
Export-Csv '!2023.01.24.AllFiles.csv' -NoTypeInformation -UseCulture
```

The `Sort-Object` doesn't change the content of the records, just their order; so that won't be affected by, and won't affect, the inclusion of the Length property.

If you want the length in KB, MB or GB you can have PowerShell convert it for you; e.g.

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter '*.*'  -recurse -File | 
Select-Object FullName, LastWriteTime, @{Name='FileSizeInKb';Expression={$_.Length/1KB}} |
Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending |
Export-Csv '!2023.01.24.AllFiles.csv' -NoTypeInformation -UseCulture
```

Per question in comments, to round the number and include KB in the resulting value:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter '*.*'  -recurse -File | 
Select-Object FullName, LastWriteTime, @{Name='FileSizeInKb';Expression={"$([int]($_.Length/1KB)) KB"}} |
Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending |
Export-Csv '!2023.01.24.AllFiles.csv' -NoTypeInformation -UseCulture
```

Comment: Thank you.

How can I round to 0 places and append " KB" at the end? That's <Space>KB

Comment: np.  `"$([int]($_.Length/1KB)) KB"`.  `$_.Length/1KB` gives you the numeric value in KB, `[int](...)` converts that to an int (so rounds it to 0 decimal places).  "$(...) KB" creats a string that ends with space KB, and runs the code in the brackets after the dollar sign / puts the result of that in that place in the string.

Comment: I am really over my head here...
You are talking about marrying these two somehow..  

~~~
Get-ChildItem -Filter '*.*'  -recurse -File |   
Select-Object FullName, LastWriteTime, @{Name='FileSizeInKb';Expression={$_.Length/1KB}} |  
Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending |  
Export-Csv '!2023.01.24.AllFiles.csv' -NoTypeInformation -UseCulture  
~~~
```
"$([int]($_.Length/1KB)) KB". $_.Length/1KB
```

I have no idea what this should look like...
I also cannot make the formatting work in comments..

Comment: Please see my answer; I added the full example with this latest tweak at the end. FYI: To include code in comments use a single backtick at the start and end of your code; e.g. \`this is code\` renders as `this is code`

Answer (score 1):

Following the [documentation example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.3#example-11-create-calculated-properties-for-each-inputobject), to get the size in KB:

```
> $size = @{label="Size(KB)";expression={$_.length/1KB}}
> Get-ChildItem -Filter '*.*'  -recurse -File | 
Select-Object FullName, LastWriteTime, $size |
Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending |
Export-Csv '!2023.01.24.AllFiles.csv' -NoTypeInformation -UseCulture
```